# Xcode reports CBCentralManagerDelegate as not found

Tags: objective-c, swift, unity-game-engine, plugins

I need some kind of advise

I am trying to implement Unity BLE Ios plugin. I've got issue while I am trying to build project in xcode:
Unknown class name 'CBCentralManagerDelegate'; did you mean 'CBCentralManager'?

Here is some part of generated header wrapper

````
@interface BLEManagerImpl : NSObject <CBCentralManagerDelegate>
- (NSString * _Nonnull)getDiscoveredDevices SWIFT_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT;
- (BOOL)startScanningWithTimeout:(double)timeout SWIFT_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT```
````

Answer (score 0):

The CBCentralManagerDelegate is not import, you should

```
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>
```